# How to solve this differential equation in closed vector form?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I am interested in calculating the orbit of a mass around a spherical object given the initial conditions. $\overrightarrow{r_{0}}$ is the initial position and initial velocity $\overrightarrow{r^{'}_{0}}$.

The differential equation that will be used in here would be: 
$$\dfrac{d^{2}\overrightarrow{r}}{dt^{2}} = -\dfrac{\overrightarrow{r}}{r^{3}}$$
Is there a way to get a closed form solution of this equation? Is there a way to solve this equation in this vector form without changing it into another coordinate system?

Comment: This might be better in Physics  than here

Comment: To make it more maths. I'll edit the question.

Comment: It is a well known system.  You might get an answer in either group but I think that you may get it quicker there.